# Change of variables in the following PDE's

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I am currently reading a paper where the following PDE's are considered:

$a_t = a_{xx} -ab$  $,$ Eq. (1)

$b_t = b_{xx} -ab$  $,$ Eq. (2)

where the subscripts $x$ and $t$ denote partial derivatives with respect to space and time.
The author transformed the above equations from $x$ and $t$ to $\eta$ and $t$ where

$\eta = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{t}} $.

He then obtained

$a_t -\frac{\eta a_{\eta}}{2t} = \frac{a_{\eta\eta}}{4t} -ab$  $,$ Eq. (5) and

$b_t -\frac{\eta b_{\eta}}{2t} = \frac{b_{\eta\eta}}{4t} -ab$ $,$ Eq. (6).

I have some difficulties to obtain Eq. (5) from Eq. (1) (or equivalently, Eq. (6) from Eq. (2)). My problem is with the term $\frac{\eta a_{\eta}}{2t}$. I do not see where this comes from. I believed at first that it came from changing the variable in $a_{t}$ but apparently no since $a_t$ still appears in Eq. (5). Can someone provide the details to obtain Eq. (5) from Eq. (1)  ?

Answer (score 0):

We have - $$ \eta = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{t}} $$ or $$x = 2\eta\sqrt{t}$$
So,
\begin{align}
 a_x &= \frac{\partial a}{\partial (2\eta\sqrt{t})} \\ 
 &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial a}{\partial \eta} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial (\eta\sqrt{t})} + \frac{\partial a}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial (\eta\sqrt{t})}\right)\\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial a}{\partial \eta} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} + \frac{\partial a}{\partial t} \frac{2\sqrt{t}}{\eta}\right)\\
 &= \frac {a_\eta}{2\sqrt{t}} + \frac {a_t \sqrt{t}}{\eta} \\
\end{align}

By a similar process, we can get $a_{xx}$.

Comment: Dear Deo, thank you for you answer. I understand your derivation of $a_x$ and I tried to get $a_{xx}$ but still I was not able to recover Eq. (5), maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: So this is what I did: $a_{xx} = \frac{\partial}{\partial(2 \eta \sqrt{t})}$ $\left(\frac{a_{\eta}}{2 \sqrt{t}}+ a_{t} \sqrt{t}/\eta \right)$. I am not sure how to do the next steps.

Comment: When I do the same for $a_{xx}$, I now obtain second derivative with respect to time that do not appear in Eq. (5).

Comment: If possible, can you share the paper that you are reading?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer Here:
http://www.lmm.jussieu.fr/~lagree/COURS/M2MHP/SSS.pdf 
Paragraph 3.8. The transformation and demonstration are given, in case it could be of interest to anyone.